# Use Roman Page Number in setcounter{page}

Tags: page-numbering

I would like to use the page number of a label as the input for `\setcounter{page}{label's page}`.
I tried using `zref` `abspage`, however, in my document there are a few uncounted pages before I start with the actual page numbering, therefore `abspage` is offset by 2 pages.
I also tried it with `newcommand` and variables, but I could not get it to work properly. An additional hurdle seems to be the roman style of page numbering making it hard to convert (got -1 using etoolbox's `\rmntonum`).

How can I resume the roman page numbering using a label placed at the end of the first part, before arabic numbering is used?
The solution should be as generic as possible, i.e. not subtracting a hard coded offset.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    this is my title
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage

    some declarations
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage

    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures
    \label{end of intro}
    \newpage

    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{chapter one}
    \lipsum[2-5]
    \cite{kastenholz}

    \chapter{chapter two}
    \lipsum[2-4]

    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{3}    % <-- set this value based on label 'end of intro', zref abspage gives 4

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References} 
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have to use a `\label`? You might as well use a `\newcount` and use its value to set your counter:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newcount\pagebak

\begin{document}
    this is my title
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage

    some declarations
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage

    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures
    \pagebak=\arabic{page}
    \label{end of intro}
    \newpage

    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{chapter one}
    \lipsum[2-5]
    \cite{kastenholz}

    \chapter{chapter two}
    \lipsum[2-4]

    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    %\setcounter{page}{3}    % <-- set this value based on label 'end of intro', zref abspage gives 4
    \setcounter{page}{\numexpr\pagebak+1}    % <-- set this value based on label 'end of intro', zref abspage gives 4

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References} 
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with `zref`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % no need for \addcontentsline
\usepackage[user,abspage]{zref}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\startfront}{\clearpage\pagenumbering{Roman}\zlabel{startfront}}
\newcommand{\startmain}{\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}\zlabel{startmain}}
\newcommand\startback{%
  \clearpage
  \pagenumbering{Roman}%
  \setcounter{page}{%
    \numexpr
      \zref@extractdefault{startmain}{abspage}{0}-
      \zref@extractdefault{startfront}{abspage}{0}+1
    \relax
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
this is my title
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
some declarations
\clearpage

\startfront
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\startmain

\chapter{chapter one}
\lipsum[2-5]
\cite{kastenholz}

\chapter{chapter two}
\lipsum[2-4]

\startback

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

The details are hidden in `\startfront`, `\startmain` and `\startback`.

Note that you need no `\addcontentsline` instructions.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, I knew that it had to be possible with zref, but could not figure it out. However, the answer by skillmon is easier for me because (for now) I don't use the `zref` package.
The `tocbibind` package is quite handy, thanks for the hint.